# Lazarus DBGrid totally blank after record commit

Tags: lazarus

I have been using [Lazarus 2.x](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/) (free pascal) with [firebird 3](https://firebirdsql.org/) (via flamerobin) and i try to commit records via TSQLConnection, TSQLQuery, TDBConnection in data module (appeals) etc.

I run the following code snippet and the records are successfully commited to firebird, but unfortunately DB connection afterwards is lost and thus there is not any record to be seen via DBGrid (not even column headers - totally blank). I have to terminate the application and reopen it to gain visual insight of my firebird via DBGrid.

Button click event

```
  appeals.SQLTransaction1.Active:=false;

  appeals.SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='UPDATE appeals set name=:name,date_entry=:entry,date_suspended=:suspended,'+
  'date_court=:court,date_judgement=:judgement where id='+IntToStr(row_num);

  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString:=Trim(Edit1.Text);
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('entry').AsDate:=DateTimePicker1.Date;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('suspended').AsDate:=IncDay(DateTimePicker1.Date,10);
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('court').AsDate:=DateTimePicker2.Date;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('judgement').AsDate:=IncDay(DateTimePicker2.Date,20);

  appeals.SQLTransaction1.StartTransaction;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  appeals.SQLTransaction1.Commit;
```

I have also used .CommitRetaining as exactly mentioned in lazarus forum without success. Any idea what could i do in order to see my records live in DBGrid after commit.

Regards

Comment: The reason the DBgrid shows nothing is that SqlQuery1.ExecSQL does not return a result set, so SqlQuery1 cannot supply any records for the DBGrid to display.  So call SqlQuery1.Open after your Commit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just got EDatabase Error, SQLQuery1: Can not open a non-select statement. Problem again! As i am new to delphi programming (by the way lazarus is a great tool), could you write down a code snippet what should i do, perhaps another SqlQuery and how? That would help me a lot!  Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the DBgrid shows nothing is that SqlQuery1.ExecSQL does not return a result set, so SqlQuery1 cannot supply any records for the DBGrid to display. So call SqlQuery1.Open after your Commit.

However, before you can call SqlQuery1.Open, you need to give it a SELECT statement to Execute, because a SQL UPDATE statement does not return a result set, as you have already found.  So, do something like:

```
  [...]
  appeals.SQLTransaction1.StartTransaction;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  appeals.SQLTransaction1.Commit;

  appeals.SQLQuery1.Sql.Text := 'Select * from appeals where ...';
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Open;
```

obviously replacing '...' in the 'where' clause by something appropriate.  Normally. a SELECT query should be parameterised to limit the number of rows returned and the amount of time the table is locked on the server.